# Updating text box widget in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

My text widget is not updating. I use serial communication from an android phone and receive by bt module. Please help. I try to use after(time, function_name) but nothing happens. Can anyone tell me what's wrong with this codes. I think i forgot something. Thank you. Here is my codes

```
    from serial import *
    from tkinter import *

    serialPort = "/dev/ttyAMA0"
    baudRate = 9600
    bluetoothSerial = Serial(serialPort , baudRate, timeout=1) 

    app = Tk()
    app.wm_title("Wireless Notice Board")

    scrollbar = Scrollbar(app)
    scrollbar.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)

    serBuffer = ""

    def readSerial_data():
      while True:

          z = bluetoothSerial.readline().decode()      

          if len(z) == 0:
             break

          global serBuffer

          if z == '\r':
             z = '' 

          if z == '\n':
             serBuffer += "\n" 

             #datalog.insert('0.0', text_data)
             serBuffer = "" 

             print(z)
          else:
             if z == "CLEAR":
              datalog.delete('1.0', END)

             else:
                def split():
                   while True:
                      a,b,c,d,e = z.split(',')                

                      datalog = Text (app, width=200, height=50,bg = e, foreground = c, takefocus=0, font = (b, 32))
                      datalog.pack()

                      datalog.insert('0.0', a)
                      serBuffer += a
                      print(a)

                      print(b)
                      print(c)
                      print(d)
                      print(e)

                      datalog.config(yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)
                      scrollbar.config(command=datalog.yview)

                  app.after(10, split)

              app.after(100, split)


        app.after(10, readSerial_data) 


    app.after(100, readSerial_data)

    app.mainloop()
```

Comment: try this: `datalog.insert(INSERT, a)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python tkinter making serial work with buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52907963/python-tkinter-making-serial-work-with-buttons)

Comment: I don't know if it will help, but to manually update tkinter widget `foo`, call `foo.update()` and `foo.update_idletasks()`.